# How to open a DialogFragment written in Kotlin class from a Java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I created a WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment, please correct if I have not written it correctly.

WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment.kt

```
class WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

@Inject
private lateinit var app: App

fun newTargetInstance(): WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment {
    val fragment = WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment()
    return fragment
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    app!!.bus.post(ScreenDimEvent(false))

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!.applicationContext)

    // Get the layout inflater
    val inflater = activity!!.layoutInflater

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    val inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_water_quality_cheks, null)

    builder
            .setView(inflatedView)
            .setCancelable(false)
            /*
             * setPositiveButton and setNeutralButton are also set (and overridden) in {@link #onStart}
             * to stop Android automatically closing the dialog on click
             */
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.fuel_order_signature_dialog_save) { dialog, id ->

            }
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.fuel_order_signature_dialog_clear) { dialog, id ->

            }


    val dialog = builder.create()

    // Stop touch events outside the dialog from cancelling/dismissing
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    return dialog
}

interface WaterQCChecksDialogListener {
    fun onDialogPositiveClick(dialog: WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment)

    fun onDialogNegativeClick(dialog: WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment)
}
}
```

ServiceOrderDialogHelper.java

```
public void showWaterQCChecksDioalog(){
    //Cannot call newTargetInstance() method.
    waterQualityChecksDialogFragment = WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment.newTargetInstance()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `newTargetInstance()` inside `companion object` to make this `static` like `java`

```
companion object {
    fun newTargetInstance(): WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment {
        val fragment = WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment()
        return fragment
    }
}
```

And call from `java` like below:

```
WaterQualityChecksDialogFragment.Companion.newTargetInstance();
```

Comment: thank you very much, and can you suggest if you think are required in the DialogFragment it self

Comment: It's good to go, Try with running your code. Please keep your post limited to single question. It's recommended in **SO**. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code, it may helps you

```
 class DialogClassSample : DialogFragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): DialogClassSample {
        val dialog = DialogClassSample()
        return dialog
    }
}



override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    isCancelable = false
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, container, false)
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setListener()
}

fun setListener() {
    button.setOnClickListener({
        dismiss()
    })
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val window = dialog?.window
    val size = Point()
    val display = window?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay
    display?.getSize(size)
    val width = size.x
    window?.setLayout((width * 0.85).toInt(),    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    window?.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
  }
 }
```

and call fron your class

```
   val dialog = DialogClassSample.newInstance()//show dialog description according to user type
        dialog.show(activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction(), DialogClassSample::class.java.name)
```

In on resume we have set dialog size dynamically ,because in some bigger size dialog its look not good so you can use as  per your requiremnent